# Is there a way to automatically execute a Python file when quitting Spyder (sort of like the opposite of startup)?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, exit, autoexec

Spyder can execute code on startup; one can even run a whole .py file when Spyder is first launched. I was just wondering if there was something similar for when Spyder is closed? That is, automatically execute a .py file when you close/exit Spyder (so the file would be executed just before Spyder is closed)?

Comment: try to ask to spyder-mens : https://groups.google.com/g/spyderlib

Comment: @pippo1980: Thanks for the suggestion, just posted a message there.